# External command from python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def OnClick(self,event):
    print "a:", a
    os.system('iperf -s -w a')
```

Here a is displayed correctly. But in the `os.system` command the value of a is taken as 0.
Could you please help me on this?

Comment: Try creating this command separately to avoid such errors. Something like <command = 'iperf -s -w {}'.format(a) >  or if 'a' is always string then you can also use %s. <command = 'iperf -s -w %s'%a >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing the value of `a`, but you are passing `a` as it is. So, you might want to do this

```
os.system('iperf -s -w {}'.format(a))
```

Now, the value of `a` will be substituted at `{}`. You can see the difference between both the versions by printing them

```
print 'iperf -s -w {}'.format(a)
print 'iperf -s -w a'
```

Comment: thank u..got it..Could you please tell me any other ways to call an external command and the output of the command has to be displayed also..

Comment: @user3131595 You might want to look at [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

Comment: >>> subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'subprocess' is not defined
>>>

Comment: Did you `import subprocess`?

Comment: @user3131595 Can you please add the updated code to the question?

Comment: def OnClick(self,event):
 subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"]) # here I have to replace the iperf command

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello1.py", line 56, in OnClick
    subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
#This the error i get

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're expecting `ls -l` to work on Windows?

Comment: no..i just gave it as an example..i have to replace it with an iperf command "iperf -s -w 1024KB"

Answer (score 0):

```
os.system('iperf -s -w a')
```

takes literal a and not the value of the variable. I would use:

```
cmd = 'iperf -s -w %d' %a
os.system (cmd)
```

Refer [input output formatting in python](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)